# Google Chrome quit unexpectedly: (caused during web scraping work on my mac)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Now i'm building python script to get data from website.
It's working well at first.
but then after I have run my code several time to test if it's works,
I got this error.
`bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable`
and chrome driver is not starting at all.
It's just flickering out after a moment.
I can't test any more.
I thought this was website protection, but actually chrome is not working either after that.

Have any idea?
why is this happening and what is the best solution?
pls leave comments and answers.
thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory': './'}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path = './chromedriver', options=chromeOptions
    )

driver.get(my_url)
...
driver.close()
```

Comment: now got this *error*: `Traceback (most recent call last):`

Comment: `BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable`

Comment: found a solution now: replace existing *chromedriver* exe file. looks like it's damaged. i'm not sure why this happened.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error a couple of times. I believe it was because I never quit the browser, and only closed it.

What happens is that every time you run this script, the browser takes us storage in your system (as browser cache, I think), so at some point the system runs out and cannot call the browser again.

You can escape this by following your `browser.close()` with a `browser.quit()` command.